# How to move rectangles in canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Hello as the title says I'm trying to move the rectangle inside my canvas. the rectangle that I'm trying to move is colored blue. I copied a code for the keyboard inputs but it seems to be not working for me. Sorry for posting the whole code.

[image: screenshot of my output]

```
var can = document.querySelector('canvas');
can.style.position = 'absolute';
can.style.top = "25%";
can.style.left = "30%"; // for positioning canvas also note that if I use the div to wrap around canvas the fillrect gets blurry


const maze = [
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2],
];

const c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
const ctx =c.getContext("2d");
const BLOCK_SIZE = 22;


for (i = 0; i < maze.length; i++){
    
    for( j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
        
        if(maze[i][j] == 1){
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fillRect(BLOCK_SIZE * j, BLOCK_SIZE * i, BLOCK_SIZE , BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
        if(maze[i][j] == 2){
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fillRect(BLOCK_SIZE * j, BLOCK_SIZE * i, BLOCK_SIZE , BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
        
    }
}

let player = {
    x: BLOCK_SIZE,
    y: BLOCK_SIZE,
    width: 22,
    height: 22,
};



    ctx.fillStyle = "#2a6592";
    
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);



player.document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
    }
  
    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y - 22, player.width, player.height);
        // code for "down arrow" key press.
        break;
      case "ArrowUp":
     
        // code for "up arrow" key press.
        break;
      case "ArrowLeft":
     
        // code for "left arrow" key press.
        break;
      case "ArrowRight":
      
        // code for "right arrow" key press.
        break;
      default:
        return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
    }
  
    // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  }, true);
  // the last option dispatches the event to the listener first,
  // then dispatches event to window
  update();
```

Help me please and thanks in advance to everyone. I'm new here so I don't really know much about this so I'm sorry

Comment: "*it seems to be not working*" - This is not a good question. What is not working? Are you receiving any errors? What's supposed to happen. Please pin-point the actual problem

Comment: the keyboard input doesn't work and wont move the blue rectangle

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you most likely run into is that you're trying to access player's (which is an object) property "document" which it doesn't own. You probably want to add a listener to document itself.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
if (event.defaultPrevented) {
  return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
}

switch (event.key) {
  case "ArrowDown":
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y - 22, player.width, player.height);
    // code for "down arrow" key press.
    break;
  case "ArrowUp":
 
    // code for "up arrow" key press.
    break;
  case "ArrowLeft":
 
    // code for "left arrow" key press.
    break;
  case "ArrowRight":
  
    // code for "right arrow" key press.
    break;
  default:
    return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
}

// Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  }, true);
```

Don't forget to implement functions for each case: a function for clearing player's rectangle with current coordinates -> changing player's coordinates inside switch -> a function for creating player's rectangle with updated coordinates.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to do that,  I don't know how to implement those functions sadly